# Applying 'for loop' in wget

Tags: bash, for-loop, bioinformatics, wget

I am trying to get a for loop to work, fetching (wget) from a website through a list of files saved as `list`, using the above code

```
for f in `cat list`; do wget --header='Content-type:application/json' 'https://grch37.rest.ensembl.org/ld/human/${f}/1000GENOMES:phase_3:CEU?content-type=application/json;window_size=500;r2=0.8;attribs=yes'
-O - > ${f}.json; done;
```

Here is the content of my `list` file

```
rs10023056
rs10025704
rs10026092
rs10026790
rs10028892
```

There is an error where the for loop cannot pass the correct name from `list` to the for loop, resulting in the error as stated below.

```
--2022-07-27 12:05:21--  https://grch37.rest.ensembl.org/ld/human/$%7Bf%7D/1000GENOMES:phase_3:CEU?content-type=application/json;window_size=500;r2=0.8;attribs=yes
Resolving grch37.rest.ensembl.org (grch37.rest.ensembl.org)... 193.62.192.83
Connecting to grch37.rest.ensembl.org (grch37.rest.ensembl.org)|193.62.192.83|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2022-07-27 12:05:22 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

It seems to be the names in my `list` file are replaced with $%7Bf%7D.

Could someone help me in this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variables from being expanded. You need double quotes to let the variable in your URL expand. When reading from a file, usually it's preferable to use a while-loop:

```
while IFS= read -r rsid; do
  wget \
    --header='Content-type:application/json' \
    "https://grch37.rest.ensembl.org/ld/human/${rsid}/1000GENOMES:phase_3:CEU?content-type=application/json;window_size=500;r2=0.8;attribs=yes" \
    -O - > "${rsid}.json"
done < list
```